# Is Mordell conjecture true for local field?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Suppose $K$ is a local field (finite extension of $\mathbb Q _p$), and $X/K$ is a genus $>1$ projective smooth curve. Is it true that $X(K)$ is finite? (I think it's false, but could you give an counterexample?)

Comment: This is never true unless $X(K)$ is empty. For instance, see Proposition 3.5.75 of Poonen's book: https://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/Qpoints.pdf

Comment: For a concrete counterexample, take $X\colon y^2 = x^5 + 1$ and $p$ any odd prime (the argument can be modified for $p=2$ too). Let $x_0\in p\mathbb Z_p$. Since the equation $y^2 - (x_0^5 + 1)$ has a solution in $\mathbb F_p$ with simple roots, by Hensel's lemma, it has a solution $y_0\in \mathbb Z_p$. So $(x_0, y_0) \in X(\mathbb Q_p)$. This type of argument works very generally.